# How get list of clients of PHP server with socket

Tags: php, sockets, ws

I use LAMP and I want to get list of clients connected to the server.

I have a panel and users session and active users must be handled.
Some users can login in multi browsers and some users can login but with limit number.
Admin of panel must see list of clients and the IP and browsers and by decision admin terminate session of user.
If user close browser or tab, remove from list instant.

How can I do that with PHP socket? I don't have basic knowledge of PHP socket, I use cookie for authentication.

Comment: sockets are irrelevant here... whenever a loggedin user makes a action, write the moment + user id into a database... then you know roughly, who is online (consider those who made the last action within the last 10 or 20 minutes).

Comment: @LarsStegelitz I know, but I want to update the list immediately, on socket close.

Comment: Forget sockets, you don't have a socket connection at this point. The browser connected to the webserver, but you don't ever see this socket... 
Do what I said as first or as very last action, a request should merely take fractions of a second, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Do you want a list of users and its socket conection ?

Comment: @Csharls List of socket connections its it is enough.

Comment: You can't, because sessions aren't sockets

Comment: @Fakhamatia No it's not. When the browser finishes downloading the page, it may close the socket.

Comment: Can you add the code, to see what things  have you tried so far?